# Should you register new extensions with Apple?

Tags: macos, apple-developer

Do I need to register new extension types with Apple before I release an application that would create them on OS X?

Comment: Quite a funny question. I wouldn't be so surprised if Apple had such a requirement.

Comment: how is the [tag:adc] tag relevant here?

Comment: At the time 12 years ago adc stood for apple developer connection ... but this is the issue with acronyms they never contain all the information, so happy for the tag to be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no need to register extensions.

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up, there is a little more information in the FAQs at the Apple Developer Connection (ADC) website:

http://developer.apple.com/faq/datatype.html